# Can't run new firebase in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, firebase

I'm following along with [this talk from google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RjfoNnxKGA). However I can't instantiate a firebase object.

I have a `package.json` file and started with:

```
npm install firebase --save
```

Then did the following:

```
let Firebase = require('firebase');
let myFire   = new Firebase('[link to my app]');
```

However, when I run the `johhny-five` app from terminal, I get the error: `Firebase is not a function`.

How am I supposed to intstantiate the object? Did Firebase change their API?

<sub>Note: I injected it into the repl and running *>> typeof Firebase* I get that it's actually an 'object'.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they changed the API, take a look: [Upgrade your Web / Node.js app from Firebase.com](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web).

This is how you do it now:

```
// See https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#project_setup for how to
// auto-generate this config
var config = {
  apiKey: "apiKey",
  authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
```

To get the `config` values, go to the URL at the top of the previous code, [Add Firebase to your Web Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup), which guides you to do the following:

> To add Firebase to your app, you'll need a Firebase project and a short snippet of code to add to your application HTML that has a few details about your project.
>
> 1. Create a Firebase project in the Firebase console, if you don't already have one.
>
>    - If you already have an existing Google project associated with your app, click Import Google Project. Otherwise, click Create New Project.
>    - If you already have a project, click Add App from the project overview page.
> 2. Click Add Firebase to your web app.
> 3. Click Copy, then paste the code snippet into your application HTML.

Comment: Ok ..Now, I got the databaseURL but don't know where to find the apiKey and authDomain

Comment: there's a link at the top of the code that guides you, added a reference in the answer

Comment: Great answer @JaimeGómez